Access to virtuemart order status comment in plgVmOnUpdateOrderPayment event
When Virtuemart order status is changed I want to send new order status with it's comment to user. The comment is saved in comments field of virtuemart_order_histories table.
To do this I use plgVmOnUpdateOrderPayment event.
    function plgVmOnUpdateOrderPayment($virtuemart_order,$old_status) {
     // getting the new status 
     // $virtuemart_order->order_status
   
    }

How to access to the comment of new status in the event?
